# Defer Parsing of Javascript - GTMetrix.com

Tags: javascript, web, pagespeed, gtmetrix

I am running a test for my site (mustangzaaubasketball.com) and one of the flags that are showing are for defer parsing of javascript.

The confusing thing for me is that I am loading these scripts closer to the footer of my html.  Also, I do not have any inline  tags in my home page despite what the report is showing.  Any help would be appreciated.

**This is what is showing in the results:**

```
370.7KiB of JavaScript is parsed during initial page load. Defer parsing JavaScript to reduce blocking of page rendering.

https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js (217.7KiB)
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js (85.7KiB)
https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.2/js/all.js (43.3KiB)
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js (20.0KiB)
https://mustangzaaubasketball.com/ (4.1KiB of inline JavaScript)
```

Comment: add defer attribute to any script tag that is not used immediately on page load

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it for me.

Comment: Okay, After 1-month research, I found a great solution for **Defer Parsing of Javascript.**
Here is my video guideline: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0AIqcFZ8rI
and Here is the JavaScript Code: https://www.ashrafularman.com/defer-parsing-of-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

Add defer attribute to any script tag that is not used immediately on page load